# React npm start works but dev server not

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start, react-scripts, devserver

Since this morning I can't launch any React JS Project in my dev server.
I explain. When I launch `npm start` command, all works fine, no any error message, all works as usual, it opens me a tab in my browser, but it loads forever and I just have a blank page loading.
For information, I works on a Windows System, with WSL Debian distro.

I tried to open it with `http://localhost:3000`, `http://127.0.0.1:3000` and with my local IP adress *(that's an exemple)* `http://192.168.0.1:3000`, I also changed browser (Chrome / Edge ), and every thing is the same.

After that I launch with `npm start` an Express project -> it works like a charm.

I also tried with a Symfony project, here with the PHP dev server `php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 -t public` and same as Express, it displays normaly in my browser.

So I'm pretty sure there is something with React, but that's on all mys REact projects, not with one particulary, and again, there is no error in my console, output is like everyday, so that's very strange and I really don't get it!
If someone has any idea

Comment: do you have any errors in the console

Comment: Not one single error